# Listbox (Listing Error)

Tags: delphi, listbox

Hi Im doing a raffle program for my friend.Everything was going good but then when i delete a value,the result was changing... Please help me!

Example:

Listbox;

- 1-a
- 2-c
- 3-b
- 4-f
- 5-h
- 6-j

After delete line 3:

- 1-a
- 2-c
- 4-f
- 5-h
- 6-j
- 6-g

What i want:

- 1-a
- 2-c
- 3-f
- 4-h
- 5-j
- 6-g

Here are the codes:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    ComboBox2: TComboBox;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Button5: TButton;
    Button6: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button6Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  b,sayac:integer;
  sonkayit,deneme:integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
sayac:=0;

listbox1.MultiSelect:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
sayac:=sayac+1;

b:=listbox1.Count + 1;

listbox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(b) + ' ' + edit1.Text);
edit1.Text:='';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a:integer;
kisi:string;

begin
Randomize;
a:=Random(b);
kisi:= listbox1.Items.Strings[a];
edit2.Text:=(kisi);

if combobox1.ItemIndex=0 then
begin
edit2.Visible:=true;
edit3.Visible:=false;
edit4.Visible:=false;
edit5.Visible:=false;
edit6.Visible:=false;
end;

if combobox1.ItemIndex=1 then
begin
edit2.Visible:=true;
edit3.Visible:=true;
edit4.Visible:=false;
edit5.Visible:=false;
edit6.Visible:=false;
end;

if combobox1.ItemIndex=2 then
begin
edit2.Visible:=true;
edit3.Visible:=true;
edit4.Visible:=true;
edit5.Visible:=false;
edit6.Visible:=false;
end;

if combobox1.ItemIndex=3 then
begin
edit2.Visible:=true;
edit3.Visible:=true;
edit4.Visible:=true;
edit5.Visible:=true;
edit6.Visible:=false;
end;

if combobox1.ItemIndex=4 then
begin
edit2.Visible:=true;
edit3.Visible:=true;
edit4.Visible:=true;
edit5.Visible:=true;
edit6.Visible:=true;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
savedialog1.FileName:='çekiliş';
if savedialog1.Execute then
begin
listbox1.Items.SaveToFile(savedialog1.FileName + '.txt');
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if opendialog1.Execute then
begin
listbox1.Items.LoadFromFile(opendialog1.FileName);
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
listbox1.DeleteSelected;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
listbox1.Clear;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Use a virtual list. Or repopulate it. The program is doing what you told it. You cannot expect the program to read your mind and re number the items. Or use a grid.

Comment: You did this listbox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(b) + ' ' + edit1.Text);. Renumber them. Or better still sore them else where, and then clear an update the listbox when there is some change. ListBox wasn't a good choice for your requirements.

Comment: Or owner-draw the ListBox and draw the numbers dynamically instead of storing them in the ListBox itself. Store only the actual edit values by themselves.

Comment: @remy Why do you suggest owner draw? Do you mean that? Or are you really suggesting using a virtual list control?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, I really meant owner-draw. The draw handler could draw an item's index followed by the item's text.  Sure, a virtual list would also work. The OnData handler would return a string that starts with the item index followed by the item's text. Different techniques, similar results in this particular situation.

Comment: @Remy Surely it's less work to do virtual.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: not really. You can do owner-draw in a few lines of code. You can do virtual in a few lines of code if you keep it simple. Boils down to personal choice which approach to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doesn't it get more tricky with themed controls? Or when VCL styles are in play?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Fine. I am dropping my case.

Answer (score 0):

`listbox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(b) + ' ' + edit1.Text);`
instead of directly adding to listbox,store both `IntToStr(b)` and `edit1.Text` seperate in two string list,and populate the listbox data from the stringlists.

also performing delete delete from the second stringlist the corresponding index,and repopulate in listbox

or you can just store the `edit1.Text` in a stringlist,and delete the string from stringlist that you delete from listbox . and populate the data in listbox with the index+string combination.....

Answer (score 0):

I would use a virtual list box here. These are the basic steps:

1. Store the data in a container other than the GUI control, for instance a string list. This is good practise in any case.
2. Set the `Style` to `lbVirtual`.
3. Implement on `OnData` event handler for the list. It needs to return a string composed of the index, and the underlying item in your container.
4. When you delete an item, delete it from the string list container and call `Invalidate` on the list box to force a paint cycle. That paint cycle will request new values by calling `OnData` and your code can supply the updated text.
5. Whenever the underlying container is modified, you must let the control know how many items it is displaying by setting the `Count` property of the list box control.

Here is a very simple example:

**Pascal unit**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Forms;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    List: TListBox;
    Delete: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var Data: string);
    procedure DeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FItems: TStringList;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: Char;
begin
  FItems := TStringList.Create;
  for c := 'a' to 'z' do
    FItems.Add(c);
  List.Count := FItems.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; 
  var Data: string);
begin
  Data := Format('%d %s', [Index+1, FItems[Index]]);
end;

procedure TForm1.DeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  for Index := FItems.Count-1 downto 0 do
    if List.Selected[Index] then
      FItems.Delete(Index);
  List.Count := FItems.Count;
  List.Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

**Associated form file**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 303
  ClientWidth = 307
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object List: TListBox
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 201
    Height = 287
    Style = lbVirtual
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    MultiSelect = True
    TabOrder = 0
    OnData = ListData
  end
  object Delete: TButton
    Left = 224
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 23
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    Caption = 'Delete'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = DeleteClick
  end
end
```